# Using round robin DNS to replace Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

As I read [this article](https://www.loggly.com/blog/why-aws-route-53-over-elastic-load-balancing/), I see there are some limitations of ELB, so I'd like to use Route53 to replace ELB.
My architecture like this [image]
I 'd like to use Route53 to replace ELB like this [image]
Can I do that? How Route53 add EC2 instance has just launched by Auto Scaling Group since the EC2's IP is automatic ip.

Comment: This is actually not a better idea. It has many problems of its own.  Also, what are you specufically using ELB for? That article seems to discuss a very specific use case... and it was written quite some time back.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for feedback quickly. 
I'm using ELB to add multiple EC2 instances with Healthy Check and using ASG to launch new EC2 instance whenever it meets the policy/condition.